# Python algorithm for finding max path in binary tree not working as desired

Tags: python, tree, binary

I was trying to write a Python algorithm that would find the maximum sum for a path of integers in a binary tree. I thought that the easiest way to do this would be a recursive function, but this doesn't seem to work the way I intended. How could I revise this function so that it would find the absolute maximum path? I can confirm that building the tree is working fine so far because the height function I wrote for it worked as intended.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.right = self.left = None
        self.data = data

class Solution:
    def insert(self, root, data):
        if not root:
            return Node(data)
        else:
            if data<=root.data:
                cur=self.insert(root.left, data)
                root.left=cur
            else:
                cur=self.insert(root.right, data)
                root.right=cur
        return root

def get_height(self, root):
    if not root or root.left == root.right == None:
        return 0
    return 1 + max(self.get_height(root.left), self.get_height(root.right))

def get_max_sum(self, root):
    if not root:
        return 0
    return root.data + max(self.get_max_sum(root.left), self.get_max_sum(root.right))
```

**IO code:**

```
 nums = '''75
    95 64
    17 47 82
    18 35 87 10
    20 04 82 47 65
    19 01 23 75 03 34
    88 02 77 73 07 63 67
    99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
    41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
    41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
    53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
    70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
    91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
    63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
    04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23'''.replace('\n', ' ')
    nums = tuple(map(int, nums.split(' ')))

    tree = Solution()
    root = None
    for i in nums:
        data = i
        root = tree.insert(root, data)

    height = tree.get_height(root)
    msum = tree.get_max_sum(root)
    print(height, msum)
```

Comment: Is this root to leaf path or [anywhere in the tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/description/)?

Comment: @ggorlen it's supposed to be root to last leaf, so traversing the whole tree. i think it's currently doing that but the value it's finding isn't the maximum path sum

Comment: root to "last leaf"? Do you mean to *any* leaf, meaning the one that provides the max path?

Comment: @trincot yes, but considering the structure of the tree i have ( a pyramid where leaves are integers with random values 0-99), it's always going to be the last one since that's the path that goes the most leaves

Comment: "goes the most leaves". If it's a root-to-leaf path, how can that path go to more than one leaf? I'm confused. Can you show expected I/O and perhaps a tree diagram illustrating what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, still confused. How do you go through a leaf? If you want to go through the most leaves, that would mean traversing the entire tree. Are you confusing "leaf" and "node"? A leaf is a node with no children, so they're terminal nodes.

Comment: @ggorlen i posted the IO for it. yeah i meant the one that goes through the most nodes TO the most leaves, guess i can't type today.

Comment: OK, after you posted your IO I think it's clear that there is some fundamental confusion about what you're trying to do. This is PE #18, and the tree you're building is a BST that has nothing to do with the input data. I suggest you scrap your approach and start from scratch.

Comment: @ggorlen is the data not supposed to be parsed as a binary search tree? that was my first inclination for this problem when it talked about designing something efficient to do it.

Comment: No, where is it suggested that it's a BST? It's not a tree, either. This is a graph problem.

Comment: @ggorlen oh ok, it was never suggested anywhere just my assumption. i thought i could interpret each number as a node with the 15th row as a bunch of leaves. thank you for the insight!

Comment: Even if that was the case, making it a BST *totally* changes the structure. [This](https://repl.it/repls/TubbyGlaringWamp) is the tree you're making. Also, this isn't a tree because `95` and `64` both have the same child, `47`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes a couple faulty assumptions about the problem which explain why it isn't working as you expect.

1. **The input is a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)), not a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))**. Looking at this sample input where we're asked to find the maximum root-to-leaf path,

   ```
      3
     7 4
    2 4 6
   8 5 9 3
   ```

   We can observe the following relationships between nodes:

   ```
         3
        / \
       ↓   ↓
       7   4
      / \ / \
     ↓   ↓   ↓
     2   4   6
    / \ / \ / \
   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
   8   5   9   3
   ```

   Because each interior node has two children, you must have (understandably) arrived at the conclusion that it's a tree. But the definition of a tree is that each child have no more than one parent, so we have a contradiction. This is actually a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).
2. **Even if it were a tree, making it a BST fundamentally changes its structure**. Consider the above input once again. Running your `insert` algorithm on it produces the following [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) structure:

   ```
            3
           / \
          /   \
         /     \
        2       7
         \     / \
          3   4   8
             / \   \ 
            4   6   9
               /
              5
   ```

   Clearly, this structure has little to do with the original input, and running a max path sum algorithm on this structure would yield `3 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 27`, when the correct answer is `3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23`.

I recommend re-formulating the problem as a graph problem and proceeding from there.